# CCSID errors querying a DB2 for IBM i stored procedure through dbExpress

Tags: stored-procedures, character-encoding, db2, ibm-midrange, dbexpress

### Background

I'm using RAD Studio XE2 with dbExpress, trying to retrieve a result set from a stored procedure residing on a **DB2 for IBM i** (AS/400).

Has **dbExpress driver** for AS/400 I use [Peter Sawatzki's](http://www.sawatzki.de/download.htm) ([seems to be the official one](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Author/175)).

The **procedure** has one smallint parameter. I query it with `CALL MYPROC(1)` in a `TSQLQuery`.

My `TSQLConnection` **parameters**:

```
DriverUnit=DbxDynalink
LibraryName=dbexpca400.dll
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverCA400
Database=192.168.81.97
User_Name=myusername
Password=mypwd
Role=MYDEFAULTSCHEMA
VendorLib=cwbdb.dll
ErrorResourceFile=
ConnectionString=
HostName=
MaxBlobSize=-1
AS400 TransIsolation=DirtyRead
CommitRetain=True
AutoCommit=True
ServerCharSet=
LocaleCode=0000
RowsetSize=-1
Connection Timeout=-1
Trim Char=False
```

### The error

When I activate the `TSQLQuery` I get

> cwbDB_Execute returned error code 6038.
>
> Server error class 2 code -403
>
> Message id: PWS0011
>
> Si è verificato un errore durante la conversione dei caratteri.
>   Causa ...: Si è verificato un tipo di errore 2 durante la conversione dal CCSID client 0 nel CCSID del server 1144. [...] 2 -- Il CCSID client o del server è 0 e non è consentito. [...]

In Italian it says **server CCSID is 1144, while client CCSID is 0, which is not allowed**.

### What I tried

So I tried to set it using **`ServerCharSet` parameter**, inspired by driver readme file, which uses `424,1255` for Hebrew. I have an Italian system with character set 695 and code page 1144. I tried many combinations for `ServerCharSet` parameter, but the best I obtained was 2 new errors:

- `ServerCharSet=695,1144` gives

  > cwbDB_PrepareDescribe returned error code 6036.
  >
  > Server error class 1 code -104
  >
  > Message id: [corrupted chars]
  >
  > [a message with corrupted chars...]
- `ServerCharSet=1144,695` gives

  > cwbDB_StartServer returned error code 6052.
  >
  > CWBNL0102 - La tabella di conversione C:\Users\Public\Documents\IBM\Client Access\02b734b0.tbl invalida o corrotta
  >
  > CWBNL0101 - Si Š verificato un errore durante il tentativo di conversione dei dati dalla code page 13488 a 695
  >
  > CWBNL0101 - Si Š verificato un errore durante il tentativo di conversione dei dati dalla code page 1144 a 695
  >
  > CWBDB0052 - Si Š verificato un errore durante la conversione dei dati
  >
  > CWBDB0052 - Si Š verificato un errore durante la conversione dei dati
  >
  > [...]

Setting **`LocaleCode` parameter** (not documented) makes no difference.

### The question

**How can I properly set client CCSID?**

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows from and a to character set.  Just setting ServerCharSet to 37 works for me:
ServerCharSet=37

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I cannot try it because I'm not working with dbExpress anymore, but I hope that someone could verify your solution and give feedback.